# Draw image as trapezium with C#

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

how can I draw an image in form of a trapezium.

I tried the Graphics.DrawImage()-function but it only accepts 3 arguments and calcuates the last lower right point by itself.

Comment: Would you like the trapezium to be the image itself, filled? Or do you want the image to be distorted into the shape of a trapezium?

Comment: If all you want is a trapezium fill - have a normal rectangular image with a transparent part in it.

Comment: The image should be distorted in the shape of a trapezium.